# Import twitter followers and following list with details such as email,phone number and company information

Tags: angularjs, twitter

I am trying to create a contact app(web app in angularjs) in which we can import contacts from other social networks such as twitter,linked in, gmail etc.

But I am stuck with twitter following and followers import in which
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

these apis are only returning twitter app related information.
Twitter is not allowing me to see my follower/following people email,phone number,and company information etc.
So my question is
1.Is there any setting that my following/follower needs to change for giving permission to give these details?
2.Is there any apis that can return these information??

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there any setting that my following/follower needs to change for giving permission to give these details?

No.  You cannot get email addresses from users you follow or are following you.

You can ask users of your app for their email adress.  In order to do this, you have to ask for your app to be [approved by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/node/1187/backlinks).

> 2. Is there any apis that can return these information?

No.  Additionally, many people don't give Twitter their phone number or company details.

Your best method is to ask each user what their details are.